# How to fix scale_color_manual error? (using ggplot2 and ggrepel)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been working with ggplot2 and ggrepel for a while and I had a problem with one of my plots (It was working perfectly but suddenly stop working and I don't know why).

Basically I'm doing a wordcloud with ggrepel and ggplot2 including 3 differents colors for each of the rows of my data. To achieve this, I used scale_color_manual. Sometimes, the data doesn't have this 3 colors so thats why I used limits. But now, it doesn't work, it only works when I remove the code of scale_color_manual.

### Data

```
data.df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"row Palabra.Final Frecuencia  NPS INDUSTRIA VA IntervaloNPS
49          años        258 8.63    Bancos SI     Amarillo
50      atención       1557 8.32    Bancos SI     Amarillo
51      atendido        387 8.95    Bancos SI     Amarillo
52        bancos       1748 7.70    Bancos SI     Amarillo
53          bien        674 9.24    Bancos SI        Verde
54          buen        258 9.27    Bancos SI        Verde
55         buena        902 9.31    Bancos SI        Verde
56       cajeras        219 7.82    Bancos SI     Amarillo
57      clientes       1042 7.65    Bancos SI     Amarillo
58        cobros        348 6.18    Bancos SI         Rojo
59     corriente        241 7.55    Bancos SI     Amarillo
61       crédito        956 7.74    Bancos SI     Amarillo
62       cuentas       1240 7.87    Bancos SI     Amarillo
64     ejecutivo       1471 7.82    Bancos SI     Amarillo
66         gente        287 7.81    Bancos SI     Amarillo
69   Información        473 8.09    Bancos SI     Amarillo
70       interés        556 7.12    Bancos SI     Amarillo
71      internet        507 8.47    Bancos SI     Amarillo
72    mantención        218 6.85    Bancos SI         Rojo
74         nunca        566 8.43    Bancos SI     Amarillo
75        pagina        539 8.15    Bancos SI     Amarillo
76         plata        295 7.39    Bancos SI     Amarillo
77      problema       1475 8.76    Bancos SI     Amarillo
78      producto        238 8.29    Bancos SI     Amarillo
79        rápida        297 9.08    Bancos SI        Verde
80     seguridad        232 9.42    Bancos SI        Verde
81        seguro        308 8.44    Bancos SI     Amarillo
82      servicio        652 7.60    Bancos SI     Amarillo
83       siempre        712 8.97    Bancos SI     Amarillo
84    sucursales        343 8.33    Bancos SI     Amarillo
85       tarjeta        798 8.16    Bancos SI     Amarillo
86         tasas        236 8.31    Bancos SI     Amarillo
87        tiempo        255 7.70    Bancos SI     Amarillo")
```

### Code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(data.df) + 
aes(x = 1, y = 1, size = Frecuencia, label = Palabra.Final, color=IntervaloNPS) +
geom_text_repel(segment.size = 0, force = 80) +
scale_size(range = c(2, 15), guide = FALSE) + scale_color_manual(name="NPS",values=c("0 - 6"= "red","7 - 8" = "yellow","9 - 10" ="green"),limits = c("0 - 6","7 - 8", "9 - 10")) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
labs(x = '', y = '') +
geom_point(size=0) +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3,linetype=0)))
```

(actually this code gives me Warning of geom_point)

I have tried a lot of differents things like:

- To Use these codes: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html
  These codes are working perfecly but I don't why in this case it doesn't.
- Detach all packages apart from ggplot2 and ggrepel.
- Close and open R.

I don't how to solve this. If someone can help it will be fabulous!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `limits` need to refer to the current levels, not the labels you want to use. Use `labels` to set the labels.

```
ggplot(data.df) + 
aes(x = 1, y = 1, size = Frecuencia, label = Palabra.Final, color=IntervaloNPS) +
geom_text_repel(segment.size = 0, force = 80) +
scale_size(range = c(2, 15), guide = FALSE) + 
scale_color_manual(name="NPS",values=c("Rojo"= "red","Amarillo" = "yellow","Verde" ="green"),limits = c("Rojo", "Amarillo", "Verde"), labels = c("0 - 6","7 - 8", "9 - 10")) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
labs(x = '', y = '') +
geom_point(size=0) +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3,linetype=0)))
```